# How can I prevent memory size exhaustion when dumping variables in Twig?

Tags: 8, theming, debugging

hello everyone i have a problem with kint , in my twig page i want to listing all variables contains int 'content' variable to make some logic on it , but the page can't loaded because the big pip memory , can any one tell me how to solve this problem to dump the 'content' variable?

> this is the msg

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 29994336 bytes) in /var/www/html/core/modules/big_pipe/src/Render/BigPipe.php on line 336
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to prevent this:

1. The most obvious one, increase memory
2. Create a new node or entity or whatever with only a single field you want to output in kint(), so the server doesn't have to run it for multiple fields
3. Make your kint() more specific, don't do kint(content) but kint(content['field_name']) for example

If none of these work, figure out how to set up xdebug, which is probably a much cleaner way of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Variable content is pretty large to print, but you can try to lower your printing depth in `modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php`

by setting `$_kintSettings['maxLevels']` to lower number than 7.

Comment: so i have just reduce the number but it shows me this error , Cannot save /var/www/html/project/web/modules/contrib/devel/kint/kint/config.default.php.
Unable to create a backup file (config.default.php~).
The file left unchanged.

Comment: Hey Patrick please try to find possible duplicates first and the flag the question accordingly to prevent duplicate answers. Many thanks